# overflow-x visible not working

Tags: css

I want to have a "floating" div that can be over all html element.
My problem is that this div can be cut by the parent (kind of overflow problem)

Even by changing z-index of the item or by changing the overflow-x value of the parent is still not working.
If I remove overflow-y property on the parent it works but I want to keep the overflow-y in auto.

You can see below my code. I want the orange div to be visible.
Thanks.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.page {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x:visible;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap; 

}

.pink {
  width: 200px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.orange {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: -100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-app>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="pink">
      <div class="orange"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it can be cut by parent? I see orange in top. What was the expected result for you?

Comment: In my code, my orange div width is 400px and part of the left part is invisible, i want it cover parent div and can be visible.@derloopkat